# JDBC - Where to find a type 4 JDBC driver for reading excel files (.xml) on Linux (or even in Windows)

Tags: java, excel, jdbc

All the examples on the net I could find listed only the **ODBC** bridge as means to access data from an excel sheet. I found one **xlsql-Y7** on **sourceforge**, but couldn't get it to work.

Any examples for some Type4 driver will be very useful with the **connection url string** applicable.

Comment: Why do things marked as code, aren't syntax-highlighted at times.. such as this ?

Comment: I see the hightlights. And perhaps you should try to use [apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/) to read excel files.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't think the SQLException thrown is of importance?

Comment: Additionally, please choose if your question is about how to get the driver you have to work, or to get suggestions for any other driver, and edit accordingly.

Comment: I have edited the question for suggestions on Type 4 drivers
@oers - Apache poi is another API altogether. I was asking for a Type 4 driver that I can use with simple JDBC

Comment: @Daud I was just recommending it because Excel always gives me the shivers. And JDBC on Top of that? Sounds like a nightmare to me :D

Answer (score 3):

If reading the data from excel is the goal, there are many libraries. for example [apache-poi](http://poi.apache.org/) suggest by Oers or [excel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I am looking for a Type 4 driver

Comment: @Daud:  It is unlikely you will have such an implementation- that too on linux. Sadly..